# Automatic ListBox Selection/SelectedItem/SelectedIndex changed while moving mouse out of ListBox

Tags: wpf, events, listbox, mouseevent

Have a `ListBox` with couple of items. Select any item (say the v.first item) and keep try to Drag it in empty area (Outside of listbox), `ListBox` selection is getting changed. Albeit I'm moving mouse in area out of `ListBox`.

I want selection change only when i move mouse within the `ListBox`.  Or completely disable the selection change while mouse move (Dragged).  Here is the snapshot of a small poc.

[image]

```
<Grid>  
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="111,49,0,180" Name="listBox1" Width="154">  
        <ListBoxItem BorderThickness="2" Height="50" Width="Auto" Name="heig" BorderBrush="Chocolate">Rohit Item 1</ListBoxItem>  
        <ListBoxItem Height="50" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Blue"  >Vivek</ListBoxItem>  
        <ListBoxItem Height="50" BorderBrush="Cyan" BorderThickness="2"  >Gaurav</ListBoxItem>  
        <ListBoxItem Name="height" Height="50" BorderBrush="CornflowerBlue" BorderThickness="2" >Asit Item 2</ListBoxItem>  
    </ListBox>  
</Grid>`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should capture the mouse while dragging, preventing other input from happening while you are dragging. This is done when drag starts:

```
Mouse.Capture(listBox);
```

Comment: Tried but not working. Still selection getting changed. I tried mouse capture in DragEnter, DragOver events of listbox

Comment: The problem there is the selection can change between mousedown and dragstart (i.e. during the drag-detecction distance).  This becomes a problem when you cross an ListBoxItem's boundary during that distance as you've clicked on one item, but a different item is selected when the drag actually occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over this topic again and I have to tell you that there is no perfect solution but a, imho, good workaround. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667998/prevent-wpf-listbox-from-selecting-item-under-mouse-when-layout-changes)